# C# unit test with mocking for VBScript

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vbscript, mocking

I have made changes to a VBScript (.vbs) that needs testing.

These are some VB6 classes defined in `.cls` files. The VBScript requires the objects of these classes.

My changes are limited to only one function in the VBScript that requires an object for just one of the classes.

I want to avoid having to run the entire script and initiate all the objects.

Is there any way, I can write unit tests to test my part of the script and mock the object that I need to pass?

Comment: Usually VBScript files are `.vbs` extension are you sure this is VBScript and not VB.Net *(which does use a `.vb` extension)*?

Comment: So the VBScript calls a COM exposed .Net assembly? Can you at least show some of the code the `CreateObject("...")` in the VBScript file and may be some of the VB.Net class code?

Comment: Updated my question. VBScript works on an object of a VB6 class

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am using C# unit tests to mock VB6 COM classes using RhinoMocks:

1. Registered the COM component (ABC.dll) on my machine using regsvr32. This also required me to register all the types and assemblies that were being used by the VB6 classes.
2. I then added reference to the COM component (ABC) by Add Reference > COM > ABC
3. I am using .Net 4.5.1 Framework and when I add reference to a COM component, it creates an interop assembly for me (Interop.ABC.dll)
4. Right click the properties of the dll and ensure that Embed Interop Types is set to True. This allows all the unknown datatypes in the COM interface to be exposed as dynamic. This also allows you to use the interop library without having the types within registered on your machine.
5. I can now use the COM interfaces exposed through the interop library using mocking frameworks. I started with using NSubstitute. However, since I have Embed Interop Types as true, most of my exposed interface properties are of the type dynamic (as opposed to object). NSubstitute does not support mocking dynamic get properties (I was able to mock dynamic set properties though). Hence, I am using RhinoMocks.
6. I am using the Microsoft Script Control library to load the script and run the method within to be unit tested

**Note:** I am new to COM :) So if you are an experienced COM user, please feel free to edit my answer for corrections or providing more details, links, etc.